# ELB backend connection errors when deregister ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I've written a custom release script to manage releases for an EC2 autoscaling application. The processing works like so...

1. Create an AMI based on an application git tag.
2. Create launch config.
3. Configure ASG to use new launch config.
4. Find current desired capacity for ASG.
5. Set desired capacity to 2x previous capacity.
6. Wait for new instances to become healthy by querying ELB.
7. Set desired capacity back to previous value.

This all works fairly well, except whenever I run this, the monitoring for the ELB is showing a lot of backend connection errors.

I don't know why this would be occurring, as it should (based on my understanding) still service current connections if the "Connection draining" option is enabled for the ELB (which it is).

I thought perhaps the ASG was terminating the instances before the connections could finish, so I changed my script to first deregister the instances from the ELB, and then wait a while before changing the desired capacity at the ASG. This however didn't make any difference. As soon as the instances were deregistered from the ELB (even though they're still running and healthy) the backend connection errors occur.

It seems as though it's ignoring the connection draining option and simply dropping connections as soon as the instance has been deregistered.

This is the command I'm using to deregister the instances...

```
aws elb deregister-instances-from-load-balancer --load-balancer-name $elb_name --instances $old_instances
```

Is there some preferred method to gracefully remove the instances from the ELB before removing them from the ASG?

Comment: Do you have connection draining enabled?

Comment: Yes I have connection draining enabled. Actually it appears I made an incorrect assumption about the back-end connection errors. It's not the old instances, but rather then new ones not being ready to handle the load.

Comment: next question: do you have healthchecks enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further investigation suggests that the back-end connection errors are occurring because the new instances aren't yet ready to take the full load when the old instances are removed from the ELB. They're healthy, but seem to require a bit more warming.

I'm working on tweaking the health-check settings to give the instances a bit more time before they start trying to serve requests. I may also need to change the apache2 settings to get them ready quicker.

Comment: Tip for scaling outside of application updates: In your autoscaling group, there is a setting called [Health Check Grace Period](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/healthcheck.html#health-check-grace-period) that will wait for the grace period to elapse before processing any scaling events based on the new instance's ELB health check; whatever period you end up delaying your automation to accommodate your new instances warming up, consider setting your Health Check Grace Period to the same value.